# Angular2: cannot able to use array functions on the response of Observables.forkJoin

Tags: angular, typescript

I have written a service which will join multiple http requests and call themin  parallel and work on the response return by them all.

Every http request will return array of data. At the end I want to club all requests data into single array object and send it back to component.
Please see the code bellow.

**Service.ts**

```
 System(modelId: number[]): Observable<Array<any>> {
    let apiArray = new Array<any>();
    for (let item of modelId) {
        apiArray.push(this.http.get("http:localhost/myService/models/" + item)
            .map((res) => {
                return this.extractData(res).items.map(({ id, name }) => new SystemModel(id, name, item));
            }))
    }
    let SysInModel: any = [];

    let result = Observable.forkJoin(apiArray).subscribe((results: Array<any>) => {

        results.forEach((item) => {
            let items: Array<any> = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
            items.forEach((k) => {
                SysInModel.push(k);
            })
        })
    });
    return Observable.of(SysInModel);
}
```

At the component side I am getting below result, which is not support for any array level operations. Please see the screenshot.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s]2yB.png

**Component.ts**

```
this.lookupService.System(_model)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.searchPanel.Systems = data;
            for (let item of this.searchPanel.Systems) {
                console.log(item);
            }

        },
        error => this.ShowError(error),
        () => { console.log('done'); });
```

In this component code, the loop I have written on service response is not working.

Your help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give us an example where you are trying to run array operations?

Comment: See below the code of component.  this.lookupService.System(_model)
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.Systems = data;
                for (let item of this.searchPanel.Systems) {
                    console.log(item);
                }
            },
            error => this.ShowError(error),
            () => { console.log('done');});

Comment: @Eeks33 I have update the question with component code. Please check,

Comment: So console.log(data) is the dump you're showing a screenshot of and your error is at the for of loop?

Comment: @Eeks33 - Yes, I cannot operate on the result return by service.

Comment: what if you change to: for (let item of data) {

Comment: Still no luck. Same result. Code did not consider this result as an array. Even if I check the length property of data it is returning 0, but actually it is having some elements.

Comment: any way to reproduce this in a plunker? I think it might be something outside of this scope